# cropper.js - How do you use the mouseup option for the cropend event?

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

I'm trying to have a button display to the left of the cropbox immediately after a crop area is drawn on an image (ie on mouseup).

Currently, I can only get the button to display once the user draws a cropbox area and then clicks elsewhere on the image.

Looking at the documentation, various "options" are available for the cropend event, including "mouseup", which I'm assuming is what I'm after here.

[Link to cropend event documentation](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs#cropend-1)

However, how do I actually "use" that option? I'm not familiar with what that syntax may look like...

I'll likely need to tap into something similar to target the cropstart mousedown option in order to rehide the button if the user starts drawing a new crop box, but surely I'll be able to make sense of it from the suggestions provided here.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  let cropImage = document.getElementById('image-form-cropbox');
  // ... other variables
  let cropperInstance = new Cropper(cropImage, { 
    // ... various options
    crop: function(event) {
      $('#crop-x-field').val(event.detail.x);
      // ...
    },
    cropend: function(event) {
      $('#crop-submit-button')
        .position({
          my: 'right center',
          at: 'left center',
          of: $('.cropper-crop-box .line-w'),
        })
        .show();
    },
    // ...
  });
  // ...
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help! Please let me know if you need anything further!

---

**Update 20180906T11:07:00**
The first time I draw a cropbox, the buttons will not display until I click elsewhere. However, if I then proceed to draw another crop box on the same image, the buttons do immediately display upon mouseup.

**Update 20180906T12:13:00**
I was able to fix the issue by reordering the functions. On the cropend event, first .show(), then .position(...)

I'm going to leave the question as open and unanswered for the time being however, in case there is some specific way to target the mouseup option as laid out in my initial question.